# difference between new(size) and new[size]

Tags: c++, new-operator

This is code for creating vector of size (1,len) for objects:

```
#include<iostream.h>

class vector
{
    int *vect;
    int len;
    public:
    vector(){ vect=NULL; len=0; }
    void get_data();
    void display();
};

void vector::get_data()
{
      cout<<"Enter number of elements: ";
      cin>>len;
      int *f=new int(len);
      vect=f;
      cout<<"Enter "<<len<<" values: ";
      for(int i=0;i<len;i++) cin>>*(vect+i);
}

void vector::display()
{
      for(int i=0;i<len;i++) cout<<*(vect+i)<<"    ";
      cout<<endl;
}

void main()
{
    vector v1,v2;
    v1.get_data();
    v1.display();
    v2.get_data();
    v2.display();
    v1.display();
}
```

Output:

```
Enter number of elements: 5
Enter 5 values: 1 2 3 4 5
1    2    3    4    5
Enter number of elements: 5
Enter 5 values: 6 7 8 9 9
6    7    8    9    9
9    2    3    4    5
```

Why did the first value of vector object v1 change on creating object v2 ?

When I replaced the line:
`int *f=new int(len);`  in get_data() to  `int *f=new int[len];` i got the expected result:

```
Enter number of elements: 5
Enter 5 values: 1 2 3 4 5
1    2    3    4    5
Enter number of elements: 5
Enter 5 values: 6 7 8 9 9
6    7    8    9    9
1    2    3    4    5
```

Comment: Tell whoever's making you use this compiler that accepts `void main` and `<iostream.h>` to get GCC and stop ruining your education.

Comment: You will have to add `#include <new>` and there is no header file called `#include <iostream.h>` remove `.h` from it.

Comment: @Shravan40: You don't need to include `<new>` to use basic new-expressions; just if you want the forms of placement new provided by the standard library (which aren't used here).

Comment: I'm still learning c++, so I'm certainly no expert, but it seems like you'd get an error trying to call `vector.display()` since it's a private member...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`new int(len)` allocates a single `int` object and initialises it with the value `len`. On the other hand, `new int[len]` allocates an array of `int`s of length `len`.

Compare with `int x(5);` and `int x[5];`.

When you were allocating only a single `int`, `cin>>*(vect+i);` was attempting to write to objects that have not been allocated.

Answer (score 11):

`new int(len)` creates a single integer, and initialises it with the value `len`.

`new int[len]` creates an array of `len` integers, uninitialised.